# Verify two FA token in .NET API with Remember me option

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to skip 2fa authentication and ask user password only if user had selected remember me option the first time while submitting 2FA code.

I am using JWT token authentication in .NET Core API and I cannot find any documentation/help for developing remember me option with API. Currently, I have generated 2fa code, verified it successfully but when I use remember me option as true, API creates a cookie named "Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe" and its http only.

Now remember me functionality depends on this cookie and front end app (React app) cannot read it due to cookie being http only. So is there any way to do this without cookie? or atleast make the cookie not httponly.

```
// sign in code
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(signedUser, AppUserDefaults.Password, true, lockoutOnFailure: false);
`
```

```
// verify 2fa and remember me 
await _userManager.VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, Provider, TwoFaCode);
var twofaResult = await _userManager.VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, Provider, TwoFaCode);

    if (rememberClient)
    {
      await _signInManager.RememberTwoFactorClientAsync(user);
    }
```

How to make this work without cookie or any workaround to make it work in .Net Core API? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want "Remember me" to do? Login immediately without any authentication or prompt only the second authentication? 
Cookies help you track the session, so you'll need to keep track of a session somehow.
You can try to use other information about the client to keep track of a session in the server but this is not recommended.

Comment: 1. Remember me should not ask user the 2fa code next time.

Comment: 2. How to track the session on the client side when cookie is http only? I need to find solution to this.

Comment: This isn't a best practice with MFA since you cancel it by design.  
"Cookie http only" you mean you have no encrypted ``HTTPS`` network? 
It depends, are you in LAN or WAN?

Comment: The app (both backend and front end) have to work on LAN.

Comment: `HTTPS` can be used with self signed certificates, use your organization's sign org to create certificates.  

For your question - you can use server only session management techniques.
For example:  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524522(v=vs.90)

Comment: You can also use browser information, IP, and other various user data that you can collect to try to guess what is this user. 
However in the internal it's not secure since these things can cracked or spoofed.

Comment: Another way to do it is by using web sockets that can be more real time - this way you can maintain a connection and use TCP's Keep-Alive to track the user connectivity. 
Once they close it, you'll know to close the session.